# Select multiple columns from cte via multiple subqueries optimizer plan

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

Imagine an sql query like the following. What will be a execution plan look like in oracle and postgres and why?

The parts in question are the 3 subselects with `from cte` clause.

```
with cte as (
   select
     sum(amount) sum_amount
   , count(*) my_count
   , orderid
   from order_details
   group by orderid
)
select 
  order.orderid
, (select sum_amount from cte where cte.orderid = order.orderid)
, (select my_count from cte where cte.orderid = order.orderid)
, (select orderid from cte where cte.orderid = order.orderid)
from order;
```

I guess the oracle optimizer is smart enough not to execute the cte part 3 times. But how does it do that?

Comment: What will the execution plan look like in *two* different databases?  Run it.  that is really the only way.  It depends on your table definitions, data sizes, and configuration parameters used (well, particularly in Oracle).

Comment: I did. I need an explanation why.

Comment: I'm not a database engineer but it's only logical to me that CTEs are executed once instead of executing them every time you reference them in a query. Why would you expect it to execute 3 times?

Comment: The answer is: estimates  (for in fact every possible plan) + heuristics. (modulo tuning + tweaking)

Comment: Why do you expect the scalar subquery to be executed once if you call for it for three times? The complexity of such merging may be too high for optimizer, because you may introduce `distinct`, for example, in one subquery and aggregation in another. Anyway, is this a theoretical question or you need some practical usage of such a template?

Comment: @MikhailBoyarsky . . . I would suggest that you delete this question and ask a new question, with the two execution plans *if you really want an attempt at an answer*.  That question may still not be well-received -- essentially, read the execution plans -- but at least it is tractable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I see. I had it wrong thinking that is some basic sql optimizer principle. As you may see from comments Marko and astentx have direct opposite opinions while the answer is not so obvious for sure.

Comment: If a CTE is referenced more than once, it will be materialized. That’s a heuristic, not cost based. ,

Comment: Are you referring to postgres here Bob? Because that statement is easily disproved in Oracle

Comment: As for how it does it, it creates a private temporary table for the duration of the cursor. It is shown in the execution plan you forgot to share.